# Problems reading from binary file or creating it

Tags: java, dataoutputstream, randomaccessfile

When I create the file I use the dataoutputstream to write one 'int' at a time:

```
Database.write(0)
```

Of course it doesn't say 0 it's a variable there but I printed it and the first one is 0 so I'm taking that one as an example.

Now I'm not 100% sure, but only using that line of code my file should now contain:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

right?

So when I'm trying to read the very first 4 bytes using:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("Database", "r");
raf.seek(0);

byte[] ByteArr = new byte[4];
raf.read(ByteArr, 0, ByteArr.length);
```

ByteArr should contain just 0's?

Well I printed the Byte[] and this is what I get:

```
0
4
13
-126
```

Kind Regards Captain Confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `write()` method writes a single *byte* to file. Its parameter is an int, but that int is assumed to be in the range [0, 255].

If you want to write a full 4-byte int to file, use the `writeInt()` method. Otherwise, to retrieve just the value 0 again, read one byte from the file using `read()`.

As a side note, RandomAccessFile can handle both reads and writes, so you should use it for both.

Comment: You were correct! When I hovered over write() in eclipse it said it took an int as variable so I misinterpret the meaning of it!

On a side note I'll try using the RAF! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `DataOutputStream.write(int b)` actually only writes the least significant **byte**.  If you want to write out 4 bytes you need to use `DataOutputStream.writeInt(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You're writing something in Chinese and then trying to read it in English, of course it's not going to make sense. If you want to write using [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), you must read using [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). As you see, a raw read won't understand the encoding that data streams use. Alternatively, you can read raw bytes, but then you'll have to write them as well, not use a DataOutputStream which encodes the data so that DataInputStream can decode it.